# How to display drop down menu with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I am using jQuery to display the drop down menu. It is working for single menu and displaying the proper drop down. If I used more than one menu it is displaying all drop down menus. I know, I passed the same class in jQuery but how can we use same class in multiple menus. Is it possible?

Please check my output in the snippet. If I `hover` on Menu-1 then it is also displaying the Menu-2 and Menu-3 dropdown. I have to display single drop down when hover. Can you help me with jQuery?

Here is my snippet:

```js
$(function() {
$(".menu").hover(
function() { $(".sub").slideToggle(400); },
function() { $(".sub").hide(); }
);
});
```

```css
a{
text-decoration: none;
}

.menu{
font-family: Arial;
color: #515151;
position: relative;
background-color: #763E9B;
width: 100%;
color: #fff;
}
.menu ul.main-menu{
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
}

.menu li.main-list {
margin: 20px;
float: left;
}

.menu li a{
color: #515151;
display: block;
padding: 10px 15px;
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 14px;
}

.menu ul.sub-options li a:hover{
background: #f44141;
color: #fff;
/*margin: 20px;*/
}

.sub{
background: #fff;
position: absolute;
z-index: 2;
width: 200px;
padding: 10px 0 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
box-shadow: 0 2px 4px #ddd;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
display: none;
}

a.hover-link{

font-size: 14px;
color: #fff;
z-index: 110;
display: block;
padding: 10px 0 1px 10px;
cursor:pointer;
border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
font-weight: bold;

}
.sub-options{
list-style:none;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
font-size: 11px;
}


.square:before {
     content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: -10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0;
  border-color: transparent transparent #fae0bb transparent;
  z-index: 9999;
  transform: translateX(-50%)
}
.square:after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    right: 4px;
    top: -22px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 17px 17px 17px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #ffffff transparent;
    z-index:9998;
}
.square {
   background: #fae0bb;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    /*top: 2.8em;*/
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 99999;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.menu:hover .square:before{
  border-width: 0 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>

<div class='menu'>
<ul class="main-menu">
<li class="main-list"><a class='hover-link'>Menu 1</a>
<div class="square">
<div class='sub'>
<ul class='sub-options'>
<li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>About</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Services</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</li>

<li class="main-list"><a class='hover-link'>Menu 2</a>

<div class="square">
<div class='sub'>
<ul class='sub-options'>
<li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>About</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Services</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</li>

<li class="main-list"><a class='hover-link'>Menu 3</a>
<div class="square">

<div class='sub'>
<ul class='sub-options'>
<li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>About</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Services</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</li>

</ul>

</div>
```

Comment: you are using hover on .menu class. you should use different class or id. and also different sub class too.

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.Leo the lion, Can you help me with an example?

Comment: a workarround [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dtzv41q2/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [**`$(this)`**](http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/08/what-is-this) to target each element individually. Like:

```
$(function() {
  $(".main-list").hover(
    function() { $(this).find('.sub').slideToggle(400); },
    function() { $(this).find('.sub').hide(); }
  );
});
```

Add a `<div class="clear">` before ending the `.menu` & apply `clear: both` CSS rule to it:

HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
  <ul>...<ul>
  <ul>...<ul>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".main-list").hover(
    function() { $(this).find('.sub').slideToggle(400); },
    function() { $(this).find('.sub').hide(); }
  );
});
```

```css
.clear {
  clear: both;
}

a{
 text-decoration: none;
}

.menu{
 font-family: Arial;
 color: #515151;
 position: relative;
 background-color: #763E9B;
 width: 100%;
 color: #fff;
}
.menu ul.main-menu{
 list-style: none;
 float: right;
}

.menu li.main-list {
 margin: 20px;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
}

.menu li a{
 color: #fff;
 display: block;
 padding: 10px 15px;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-size: 14px;
}

.menu ul.sub-options li a {
  color: #151515;
}

.menu ul.sub-options li a:hover{
 background: #f44141;
 color: #fff;
 /*margin: 20px;*/
}

.sub{
 background: #fff;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 2;
 width: 200px;
 padding: 10px 0 3px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 box-shadow: 0 2px 4px #ddd;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 display: none;
}

a.hover-link{

 font-size: 14px;
 color: #fff;
 z-index: 110;
 display: block;
 padding: 10px 0 1px 10px;
 cursor:pointer;
 border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
 font-weight: bold;

}
.sub-options{
 list-style:none;
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
 font-size: 11px;
}


.square:before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 top: -10px;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 0;
 border-color: transparent transparent #fae0bb transparent;
 z-index: 9999;
 transform: translateX(-50%)
}
.square:after {
 content:"";
 position: absolute;
 right: 4px;
 top: -22px;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 0 17px 17px 17px;
 border-color: transparent transparent #ffffff transparent;
 z-index:9998;
}
.square {
 background: #fae0bb;
 box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 position: absolute;
 margin: 0;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%);
 /*top: 2.8em;*/
 width: 200px;
 z-index: 99999;
 margin-top: 20px;
}

.main-list:hover .square:before{
 border-width: 0 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>

<div class='menu'>
 <ul class="main-menu">
  <li class="main-list"><a class='hover-link'>Menu 1</a>
   <div class="square">
    <div class='sub'>
     <ul class='sub-options'>
      <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>About</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Services</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </li>

  <li class="main-list"><a class='hover-link'>Menu 2</a>

   <div class="square">
    <div class='sub'>
     <ul class='sub-options'>
      <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>About</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Services</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </li>

  <li class="main-list"><a class='hover-link'>Menu 3</a>
   <div class="square">

    <div class='sub'>
     <ul class='sub-options'>
      <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>About</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Services</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </li>

 </ul>
  <div class="clear"></div>

</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: nice one..i forget to add $this. :)

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.Saurav, the My issue got resolved 100%. but I need one more help.I have to display background color with width 100%. In .menu class, i added background and width but its not working.Can you help me in this also.Please

Comment: @NarendraVerma Updated my answer. After giving the background color there are some arrows appearing below menu items that is because of `:after` on your lists. Have a look. Also don't forget to accept this answer if this helped you.

Comment: Thanks for helping  Mr.Saurav.Upvote for my side.Working perfectly for me.

Comment: It's my pleasure! @NarendraVerma